# Logitech Mouse/Keyboard (MK520) take 30 seconds to start after resuming from sleep

Tags: usb, sleep, logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver, logitech-keyboard

When I wake up my Windows 7 x64 from sleep, the MK520 set (Keyboard + Mouse) takes about 30 seconds to start working (maybe while the USB receiver and/or the devices are getting reinstalled).

All the software and firmware (Logitech Unifying Receiver, Keyboard and Mouse) is up to date.

This happens when the computer went to sleep and woke up with AC plugged-in. The power plan is set to selective suspend USB on battery, but do nothing with the Power plugged in:

[image: USB selective suspend setting]

It hasn't always behaved like this - I've had it for about 1.5 years and this only started a few months ago, so I know this is not normal behavior.

**What should I try next to get the keyboard/mouse to become responsive as soon as the computer wakes up?**

#### PC Specs

- Windows 7 x64
- Logitech MK520

Comment: Well not all USB ports are created equally.  I have an expansion on my system for extra USB ports and those ports are not recognized until later in the boot process.  You may want to try other USB ports.  Also some USB ports are powered while others might be just data.  I doubt that this would make a difference but it might.  Try plugging in your mouse or mouse dongle into those to see how long it takes to react.